# How to remove an event listener

Tags: javascript

I have nested a few event listeners into this code that will eventually link to a new page. I was going to use the same .js file on the new .html that is linked to by using the window.location method but the listeners keep on listening on the new page. How do i remove them once the new page has loaded.

I have already done a few searches online but can't find a suitable solution. Should i just create a new .js for the new page? Or is there a way to cancel all the event listeners ( There is a chunk of code for each character option)

```js
mage.addEventListener('click', e => {
  rogue.remove();
  warrior.innerText = "Actually i don't want to be a mage, i changed my mind.";
  text.innerText = "You have chosen to be a Mage. Please click again if this is correct";
  warrior.addEventListener('click', e => {
    window.location.reload();
  });
  mage.addEventListener('click', e => {
    warrior.remove();
    text.remove();
    mage.innerText = "Let's start the adventure!"
    const char = localStorage.setItem("char", "Mage");
    mage.addEventListener('click', e => {
      window.location.href = "page1.html";
    });
  });
});
```

[image: My simple interface]

Comment: Why would you ever need to NEST eventListeners?

Comment: Whatever the usecase, you should create an array and `push` the result of addEventListener and `pop` a listener and call removeEventListener with that listener as argument.

Comment: I only started learning to code two months ago so I've probably gone about it the wrong way . Initially there are three options  to choose from Mage , Warrior and Rogue. When one of the options is clicked the text is changed and one option is deleted. Then there is a choice to confirm or reselect by reseting the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do NOT want to add event listeners inside an event handler

```js
character.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const tgt = e.target.
  if (tgt.id === "mage")....
  .....  
  if (changed) window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: I had a play with the code and used if statements to detect which div was clicked based on the class rather than having multiple event listeners. Thank you for taking the time to post a solution.